# How do I change a text link that runs my script to a dropdown link?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a JavaScript that changes the output on the same page by using:

```
<"a href="#" onclick="change('Bob','0','0','2','2','1','0','0')">Bob</a>
<"a href="#" onclick="change('Sam','0','0','2','2','1','0','0')">Sam</a>
<"a href="#" onclick="change('Ted','0','0','2','2','1','0','0')">Ted</a>
```

I would like to change the links to a dropdown (select - option) form field.

Any help putting me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select size="1" onchange="change(this.value, '0','0','2','2','1','0','0')">
    <option>Bob</option>
    <option>Sam</option>
    <option>Ted</option>
<select>
```

Using `this.value` gives you the currently selected option of the select box (Bob, Sam or Ted).

---

**EDIT**

If you want to pass different parameters to your function, you can do it like this:

Javascript:

```
function selectValueChanged(value){
    switch(value){
        case "Bob":
            change('Bob','-1','0','2','4','6','0','0');
            break;
        case "Sam":
            change('Sam','0','-2','3','5','1','0','2');
            break;
        case "Ted":
            change('Ted','2','1','4','2','3','2','0');
            break;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select size="1" onchange="selectValueChanged(this.value)">
    <option>Bob</option>
    <option>Sam</option>
    <option>Ted</option>
<select>
```

So you pass your selected value to `selectValueChanged`, and this function calls the `change` function with the appropriate paremeters.

Comment: this function has 8 parameters.
Thank you w4rumy. I'm sorry but I didn't show
<a href="#" onclick="change('Bob','-1','0','2','4','6','0','0')">Bob</a>
<a href="#" onclick="change('Sam','0','-2','3','5','1','0','2')">Sam</a>
<a href="#" onclick="change('Ted','2','1','4','2','3','2','0')">Ted</a>

Comment: Try that again. Thank you w4rumy. I'm sorry but I didn't show
this function has 8 parameters.
I need to be able to send all 8. Your example only changes the first of these.
This is a correct example of what I need to post to the script.

    <a href="#" onclick="change('Bob','-1','0','2','4','6','0','0')">Bob</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="change('Sam','0','-2','3','5','1','0','2')">Sam</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="change('Ted','2','1','4','2','3','2','0')">Ted</a>

Sorry I wasn't more correct in my original post.

Comment: In this case, you can use a javascript function before calling `change` to decide which parameter to pass. See my updated answer. Don't forget to [mark this as accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you. I forgot "case". I remember now. Works great.